# Rate of change of distance between linearly moving points

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, computer-science

Writing the position and velocity of one point relative to the other, this becomes finding distance of a point to the origin, where the point is parameterized by a line:

$$s(t) = (x(t), y(y)) = (x_0 + Xt, y_0 + Yt)$$
$$||s||^2 = l^2 = x^2 +y^2$$
$$2ll' = 2xx' + 2yy'$$
$$l' = \frac{xx' + yy'}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
$$l' = \frac{(x_o + Xt)X + (y_0 + Yt)Y}{\sqrt{(x_0 + Xt)^2 + (y_0 + Yt)^2}}$$

Where $x_0, y_0, X, Y$ all constants.

I think my mind is going to mush.

1. How do I know this function is defined at the origin?
2. How can I evaluate this function at the origin using a computer, where it won't blow up (0/0 = NaN)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? This seems 10x harder then it should be

Comment: @amd I'm very confused to as what that means: I've edited question to as how I arrived there - I think it is correct, no?

Comment: I feel like something funny is going on. If $y_0$ and $Y$ are $0$, the sign of $l'$ should depend on signs of $X$ *and* $x_o$

Comment: Doesn’t it? The sign is also going to depend on $t$, of course, changing on either side of $t=-x_0/X$.

Comment: @amd Am I blind, or does the it degenerate to $l' = X$ when $y_0 = Y = 0$

Comment: You’re making a similar mistake as user115350: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, not $a$. If you think about it, $l'$ can only be a constant if the points aren’t moving.

Comment: @amd yep! I need some sort of brain-reviving treatment

Comment: Happens to all of us. I had a big d’oh! moment on a different problem a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line $s$ passes through the origin if the two moving points coincide at some time $t_0$. In that case, the distance function $l$ will be of the form $k|t-t_0|$ for some constant $k$. This is not differentiable at $t_0$, so there’s nothing strange going on here.

Comment: You my friend, are right, I believe. Thank you so much for putting your neurons to use for me :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you are right that this function is not defined at the origin. So you have to define it.

$$ll' = xx' + yy'$$ is valid for all position including the origin. And you cannot divide both side with 0 when both x and y are zero.

at the origin, $$l' = \sqrt {(x')^2 + (y')^2}$$

this is because, at origin, $$\triangle l = \sqrt {(x'\triangle t)^2 + (y'\triangle t)^2}$$ thus
$$l'=\lim_{\triangle t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\triangle l}{\triangle t} = \sqrt {(x')^2 + (y')^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Be careful. This function is not differentiable if the line passes through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$l' 
= \dfrac{(x_0 + Xt)X + (y_0 + Yt)Y}{\sqrt{(x_0 + Xt)^2 + (y_0 + Yt)^2}}
$

If there is a
$t_0$
such that
$x_0 + Xt_0
=y_0 + Yt_0
= 0
$,
then,
at $t_0+c$,

$\begin{array}\\
l' 
&= \dfrac{(x_0 + X(t_0+c))X + (y_0 + Y(t_0+c))Y}{\sqrt{(x_0 + X(t_0+c))^2 + (y_0 + Y(t_0+c)))^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{XcX + YcY}{\sqrt{(Xc)^2 + (Yc)^2}}\\
&= sign(c)\dfrac{X^2 + Y^2}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}}\\
&= sign(c)\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Where 
$sign(c)
=-1, 0, 1$
if $c<0, c=0, c>0$.
$

Comment: Which means that $l'$ is undefined at $t_0$, no? $l$ (the denominator here) has a different constant value to either side of $t_0$.

Comment: Right. At 0, it becomes 0/0.